# How to encode video then filter to change position block frame output?

Tags: ffmpeg

Lets say video with 1920x1080 3 minutes. i want to split each frame to 4 block. so each block 480x270. then, i want to put block 1 to 4 position. block 4 to 1st position. https://i.ibb.co/QkGpKN6/Naruto-Uzumaki.png

exactly i can extract frame of video to image. then, edit that image. but i got reduce quality, and the size bigger. the disadvantage, it takes twice times.

```
ffmpeg -r 1 -i input.mp4 -r 1 output_%d.jpg

// convert back image to video after  block frame set to specific position in backend.
ffmpeg -r 23.97602397602398 -i output_%d.jpg -c:v h264 -r 23.97602397602398 output.mp4
```

is there direct way to do this?

Comment: 5 filterchains: 4 with `crop` filters, and start the last one with `color` source filter (for backsplash) and place each cropped frame with an `overlay` filter (so 4 total).

Comment: @kesh show me 1 single line code

Comment: @kesh how to save crop image and use overlay directly? i know to crop and overlay. but i dont know a single line to crop and overlay directly while encode.

Answer (score 0):

FFmpeg's `-vf`, `-af`, and `-filter_complex` options accept a combination of filters as a filtergraph (commas to chain them and semicolons to have multiple chains).

For your purpose, you can try this filter combo first (before `crop`+`overlay`):

```
ffmpeg -i input -vf 'untile=2x2,shuffleframes=0 2 1 3,tile=2x2' output
```

You probably want different shuffling order. Experiment to figure it out.

Read the doc for their options: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html

EDIT

If you want to use crop-overlay instead, try

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex \
  "[0]crop=427:240:0:0[v1];\
   [0]crop=427:240:427:0[v2];\
   [0]crop=427:240:0:240[v3];\
   [0]crop=427:240:427:240[v4];\
   [0][v1]overlay=x=0:y=0[v5];\
   [v5][v2]overlay=x=427:y=0[v6];\
   [v6][v3]overlay=x=0:y=240[v7];\
   [v7][v8]overlay=x=427:y=240[out]"\
  -c:v libx264 -crf 30 output.mp4
```

Personally, I like the other approach better (a way more compact)

Another option is to use `xstack` filter instead of `overlay` filters (one `xstack` takes care of all the `overlay` ops).

Comment: `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "[0]crop=427:240:0:0;[1]crop=427:240:427:0;[2]crop=427:240:0:240;[3]crop=427:240:427:240;overlay=x=0:y=0[1];overlay=x=427:y=0[3];overlay=x=0:y=240[2];overlay=x=427:y=240[4]" -c:v libx264 -crf 30 output.mp4` is right how to save filter to variabel and use it to other filter?

Comment: See the updated response

Comment: u knows what the error is this?  this command `was expected to have exactly 1 input and 1 output. However, it had >1 input(s) and >1 output(s). Please adjust, or use a complex filtergraph (-filter_complex) instead.
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
[aac @ 000001e99a5937c0] Qavg: 65536.000
[aac @ 000001e99a5937c0] 2 frames left in the queue on closing
Conversion failed!`

Comment: and [0]crop[v1] is it variabel?

Comment: i sucess to change block to specific location. but theres gap in right. `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "[0]crop=427:240:0:0[c1]; [0]crop=427:240:427:0[c2]; [0]crop=427:240:0:240[c3]; [0]crop=427:240:427:240[c4]; [0][c1]overlay=x=427:y=240[o1]; [o1][c2]overlay=x=0:y=240[o2]; [o2][c3]overlay=x=427:y=0[o3];[o3][c4]overlay=x=0:y=0"  -c:v libx264 -crf 30 -preset ultrafast output.mp4 -y` i try to configure. 428 and the problem, theres gap in middle. i forgot to explain the video dimension is `854 x 480`

Comment: You need to toy around with `x` and `y` options of `overlay` to achieve the desired effect.